# How to create a program like Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, interface, apache-poi

I was trying to build an app that can manipulate and excel sheet.  I found Apache POI and it looks like the why to go for the interface.  However, this got me thinking, how does POI work?  What if I wanted to create my own interface?  So far I can't find any good tutorials or answers of how Apache POI works, except that it's reading XML off of excel.  Does anyone know where I can find information on how Apache POI works, or how to create a program like it?  Thanks!

Comment: There's no tutorials, how Apache POI works. It is made up of so many codes and actions. It would be nice to start with a reference document and analyze open source codes. https://poi.apache.org/index.html

Comment: There's probably about 10-15 man years worth of work gone into Apache POI, so it's quite a bit of effort to recreate, and rather pointless given Apache POI is open source + free!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to go through the source code of the POI implementation. Use Intellij which has a strong decompiler to read the code (if you don't have the source jar of POI).

Comment: Apache POI is open source, so there's no need to decompile! Just checkout from SVN or Git, details at http://poi.apache.org/subversion.html